How would I generate a circular electrical field to accelerate ions to non relativistic speeds?

Here is what I've thought up so far.

As is depicted, there exists a toroidal solenoid wrapping a highly permeable metal, with a current that is equal to $sin^2(\omega t)$. This generates a B field which wraps the torus which encases the positive charges, at the location of the electromagnet.
Maxwell's third law is
$$
\nabla \times E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}
$$
Therefore, the changing B field shall correspond to an electrical field within the charge enclosing torus, accelerating the positive ions in the opposite direction of the electrical field. Below the charge enclosing torus is a magnet, which curls the ions, so that they complete an orbit.
The charge should accelerate and deaccelerate, with the phase of the current of the electromagnet.
Does this all check out? I'm not trying to reach relativistic speeds. Just around 10,000 m/s.

I would be worried that the ions will fly out continuing on a straight path. You may need some way of keeping them on the circular path. Depending on the path diameter and the final speed, you could calculate centrifugal force that has to be overcome to keep the ions on the path.

I think your induced magnetic field drawn here will push current in the wrong direction? I believe you also need RF pulsing to "push" a "bunch" of electrons, as they pass the magnet on their round-trip resonance frequency.
